# How I send 2 integer arguments using a Timer.tick event handler

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling, arguments

I have a constructor with a Timer.tick event,

```
public PlayMe(int rows, int cols)
{
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;

    delay = new Timer();
    delay.Enabled = false;
    delay.Interval = 550;
    delay.Tick += delay_Tick;

    restart = new Timer();
    restart.Enabled = false;
    restart.Interval = 550;
    restart.Tick += restart_Tick(rows,cols);
```

How I fire both rows and cols arguments inside the Timer.Tick method?

```
void restart_Tick(int rows, int cols)
{
    restart.Stop();

    if (gameOver && lblLose.Visible)
    {
        clearBoard();
        createBoard(rows,cols);
    }

    if (gameOver && lblWin.Visible)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            clearBoard();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite:

```
restart.Tick += (object s, EventArgs a) => restart_Tick(s, a, rows, cols);
```

And the method:

```
  void restart_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e,int rows, int cols)
```